# Accessibility to the loaded flash movies

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, client-server

I need to load a flash-game inside the flash site. The goal is to get information about the winners' score to publish it on the site. The problem is that the game was developed by third-party programmers, so I have no idea if I can get access to any variable of the loaded swf (game) to get the highscores.

How can I retrieve the data from loaded swf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access the information inside another swf ( especially 3rd Party swf! ) unless they have explicitly exposed their swf to being accessed. You can check whether they have allowed access by testing the flag [childAllowsParent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#childAllowsParent).

You can alternately test to see if they are somehow emitting any events which you can catch to be notified of the high score. If the game is integrated with [Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com) or such other Flash Game hosting websites, there is a possibility that they have implemented some of the [API](http://developers.kongregate.com/docs/api-overview/intro)'s that Kongregate expects. If that is the case then you can perhaps hook onto these by emulating Kongregate.

Comment: Okay, but if there's no implementation for some API and there's no explicit access declaration - nothing can be done, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do... Unless they are explicitly publishing that data to you.